# C program Always print 0.000000

Tags: c

I have faced a problem with c program.
 In this case, whatever value I entered it's only output is `0.000000`.
 Please check this and give me a solution.

```
{
    long double x,y,m,E,c;

    printf("\t\t\t Enter a mass Hydrogen atoms: ");
    scanf("%Lf", &x);

    printf("\t\t\t Enter a mass Helium atoms: ");
    scanf("%Lf", &y);

    m=x-y;
    c=3*(1*10^27);
    E=m*c;
    printf("\t\t\t Energy: %Lf", &E);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: `^` does not mean exponential in C.

Comment: Change `printf("\t\t\t Energy: %Lf", &E);` to `printf("\t\t\t Energy: %Lf", E);`  You only need to pass the address when reading the value, not when printing it.  Also try to increase your compiler warning level - your compiler should have caught that.

Comment: Tom Karzes I changed that but the problem is still the same.

Comment: That's because there's more than just one problem with this code.  Did you fix your exponentiation error?  See the first comment.  If it's a constant, use `1.0e27` instead of `(1*10^27)`, which is just the integer `17` since `^` is the bitwise XOR operator.

Comment: Tom Karzes what can I use exponentiation in c.

Comment: If it's a constant, just write the number directly as shown above.  If it's not a constant, and you need runtime exponentiation, then you will need to `#include <math.h>`, link with `-lm`, and then you can use `pow()`.

Comment: it is constant and I add above, but still, the output is 0.000000

Comment: You need to debug it.  Find out *exactly* where the bug is.  Do `x` and `y` have the values you expect?  Print them to confirm it.  If so, move on to the next step in your program.  If not, then you've identified the problem and can look to fixing it.  You need to use deductive reasoning.  There's a lot you can do before throwing up your hands and giving up.

Comment: input values are also get 0.000000, why is that.

Comment: Ok, so *that's* what you should have posted:  A 2-line program that inputs a `long double` and then prints it.  But I don't know what your code looks like so I can only speculate at this point.  Did you remember to include `&` in the `scanf`?  Did you remember *not* to include it in the `printf`?  At this point, I suggest deleting this post, and creating a new post with your 2-line program so that you can at least figure out how to properly read and write your `long double` values.  You can't make any progress until you solve that problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention. I'll do as you said. Thanks again.

Comment: test outputting of `%Lf` without doing any calculations, there are some implementations around with bugged handling of long double

Comment: M.M my inputs are also print as 0.000000, That's the problem. If you have any solution please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the length of the format in the output, using the following notation:

`printf("\t\t\t Energy: %i.dlf", &E);`

where "i" are the integers you want to show and "d" are the decimals.
Replace "i" and "d" with other numbers and experiment.

Comment: it's significant whther `l` or `L` is used

Comment: Welcome to SO. How will this fix the wrong value? As long as an address is passed as argument for a floating point conversion specifier, number of digits etc. will not help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

while you are getting input from user its become 0 and it's result into 0.0 cause you are using %Lf insted of %lf and also to power 10 by 27 you need to use pow function of math.h

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(){

    double x,y,m,E,c;
    clrscr();
    printf("\t\t\t Enter a mass Hydrogen atoms: ");
    scanf("%lf", &x);

    printf("\t\t\t Enter a mass Helium atoms: ");
    scanf("%lf", &y);

    m=x-y;
    c=3*(1*pow(10,27));

    printf("\n%lf and %lf",x, y);


    E=m*c;
    printf("\n\t\t\t Energy: %lf", E);

    getch();

    return 0;

}
```